# Displaying Django error messages in templates? - Not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have two forms login.html and register.html, and i follow the same methods for displaying errors in templates, but does not work.

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="" class="ui large form">
{% csrf_token %}

  <div class="ui stacked segment">
    {% if not form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
        {{ form.username }}              
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
        {{ form.username }}              
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Password</label>
        {{ form.password }}              
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Password</label>
        {{ form.password }}              
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <small><p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p></small>


    <input type="submit" name="" class="ui fluid large teal submit button" value="login">



  </div>

</form>
```

Output screenshots:

[Non Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJAkR.png)

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsA7W.png)

register.html

```
<form method="post" action="" class="ui large form">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="ui stacked segment">
    {% if not form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
      {{ form.email }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
      {{ form.email }}
      <p>{{ form.email.errors }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Password</label>
      {{ form.password1 }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Password</label>
      {{ form.password1 }}
      <p>{{ form.password1.errors }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      {{ form.password2 }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      {{ form.password2 }}
      <p>{{ form.password2.errors }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
     <small><p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p></small>

    <input type="submit" name="" class="ui fluid large teal submit button" value="Sign Up">
  </div>

</form>
```

This time i don't get any error messages displayed. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: post your view also be clear which template is not working

Comment: register.html is functional.. but error message is not displayed when inside the error class..

Comment: Thats what edit your question to display views for both login and register. It will be easy debug the same.

Answer (score 1):

`non_field_errors()`, as their name implies, show errors not associated with a field ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)).

> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be associated with any field in particular. They go into a special “field” (called **all**), which you can access via the non_field_errors() method if you need to.

You shouldn't be using it as logic for whether a  specific field has an error. You should be doing this:

```
{% if not form.email.errors %}
    <div class="required field">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
      {{ form.email }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

and then in your `login.html`, you're not rendering `{{ field.errors }}` like  you do in `register.html`:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="required field error">
      <label>Emailaddress</label>
        {{ form.username }}

      {# This is missing #}
      <p>{{ form.username.errors }}</p>    

    </div>
{% endif %}
```